# get tag,id,class of an object when mouse is over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For exemple then i move mouse over this object i get its tag,id,class and can manipulate using tag,id or class in a function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var O1 = {m : 0,n : 0};
 var O2 = {m : 0,n : 0};
  O1.n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4)) + 2;
  O1.m = Math.floor(Math.random() * (O1.n - 1)) + 1;
  O2.n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4)) + 2;
  O2.m = Math.floor(Math.random() * (O1.n - 1)) + 1;
  O2.n = O1.n;
 var n = 0;
 
  generateTableAns(1,'.A1')
  generateTableAns(2,'.A2')
  generateTableAns(3,'.A3')
  generateTableAns(4,'.A4')
  generateTableAns(5,'.A5')

  //TableAns()

}); // Sfirsit Document ready


//Generarea raspunsului partea 1
function generateTableAns(total_rows, selector){
 total_rows = total_rows || 1;
 selector = selector || "body";
 var $table = $('<table>')
 for (var i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
  var $tr = $('<tr>');
  var $td = $('<td>');
  $('table tr td').css('width : 200px;');
  $tr.append($td);
  $table.append($tr);
  $td.css('background-color', 'green');
  $td.addClass('e'+(i+1))
 }
 $(selector).empty()
 $(selector).append($table);
}

 function TableAns(){
 $(".A1").on({
 click : function(){
   generateTableAns(1,'.A2')
   generateTableAns(1,'.A3')
   generateTableAns(1,'.A4')
   generateTableAns(1,'.A5')
 $('.A1').removeClass('A1').addClass('B1');
 $('.A2').removeClass('A2').addClass('B2');
 $('.A3').removeClass('A3').addClass('B3');
 $('.A4').removeClass('A4').addClass('B4'); 
 $('.A5').removeClass('A5').addClass('B5');
 $('.B1').css("border","black solid 3px");
   // $(this).off('click');
   // $(".A2").off('click');
   // $(".A3").off('click');
   // $(".A4").off('click');
   // $(".A5").off('click');
 n = 1;
 TableAnsF(n);
   },
 mouseover : function(){
  $('.A1').css("border","red solid 3px");
 },
 mouseleave : function(){
  $('.A1').css("border","black solid 3px");
 }
 });
 
 
 $(".A2").on({
 click : function(){
   generateTableAns(2,'.A1')
   generateTableAns(2,'.A3')
   generateTableAns(2,'.A4')
   generateTableAns(2,'.A5')
 $('.A2').removeClass('A2').addClass('B2');
 $('.A1').removeClass('A1').addClass('B1');
 $('.A3').removeClass('A3').addClass('B3');
 $('.A4').removeClass('A4').addClass('B4');
 $('.A5').removeClass('A5').addClass('B5');
 $('.B2').css("border","black solid 3px"); 
   // $(this).off('click');
   // $(".A1").off('click');
   // $(".A3").off('click');
   // $(".A4").off('click');
   // $(".A5").off('click');
 n = 2; 
 TableAnsF(n);
  },
 mouseover : function(){
  $('.A2').css("border","red solid 3px");
 },
 mouseleave : function(){
  $('.A2').css("border","black solid 3px");
 }
 });

 $(".A3").on({
 click : function(){
   generateTableAns(3,'.A2')
   generateTableAns(3,'.A1')
   generateTableAns(3,'.A4')
   generateTableAns(3,'.A5')
 $('.A3').removeClass('A3').addClass('B3');
 $('.A1').removeClass('A1').addClass('B1');
 $('.A2').removeClass('A2').addClass('B2');
 $('.A4').removeClass('A4').addClass('B4');
 $('.A5').removeClass('A5').addClass('B5');
 $('.B3').css("border","black solid 3px"); 
   // $(this).off('click');
   // $(".A2").off('click');
   // $(".A1").off('click');
   // $(".A4").off('click');
   // $(".A5").off('click');
 n = 3;
 TableAnsF(n);
  },
 mouseover : function(){
  $('.A3').css("border","red solid 3px");
 },
 mouseleave : function(){
  $('.A3').css("border","black solid 3px");
 }
 });
 
 $(".A4").on({
 click : function(){
   generateTableAns(4,'.A2')
   generateTableAns(4,'.A3')
   generateTableAns(4,'.A1')
   generateTableAns(4,'.A5')
 $('.A4').removeClass('A4').addClass('B4'); 
 $('.A1').removeClass('A1').addClass('B1');
 $('.A2').removeClass('A2').addClass('B2');
 $('.A3').removeClass('A3').addClass('B3');
 $('.A5').removeClass('A5').addClass('B5');
 $('.B4').css("border","black solid 3px");
   // $(this).off('click');
   // $(".A2").off('click');
   // $(".A3").off('click');
   // $(".A1").off('click');
   // $(".A5").off('click');
 n = 4;
 TableAnsF(n);
  },
 mouseover : function(){
  $('.A4').css("border","red solid 3px");
 },
 mouseleave : function(){
  $('.A4').css("border","black solid 3px");
 }
 });
 
 $(".A5").on({
 click : function(){
   generateTableAns(5,'.A2')
   generateTableAns(5,'.A3')
   generateTableAns(5,'.A4')
   generateTableAns(5,'.A1')
 $('.A5').removeClass('A5').addClass('B5');
 $('.A1').removeClass('A1').addClass('B1');
 $('.A2').removeClass('A2').addClass('B2');
 $('.A3').removeClass('A3').addClass('B3');
 $('.A4').removeClass('A4').addClass('B4'); 
 $('.B5').css("border","black solid 3px");
   // $(this).off('click');
   // $(".A2").off('click');
   // $(".A3").off('click');
   // $(".A4").off('click');
   // $(".A1").off('click');
 n = 5;
 TableAnsF(n);
  },
 mouseover : function(){
  $('.A5').css("border","red solid 3px");
 },
 mouseleave : function(){
  $('.A5').css("border","black solid 3px");
 }
 });
 
 }

// Raspuns 
 function TableAnsF(nr){
  var selector;
  for(var i = 1 ; i <= 5; i++){
   for(var j = 1 ; j <= nr; j++){
    selector = '.B'+i+' .e'+j;
   }
  }
 }


setInterval(function(){
    
    var element = $(':hover');
    if(element.length)
    {
        var domElement = element[element.length - 1];
        var tagName = domElement.tagName;
        var id = domElement.id ? ' id="' + domElement.id + '"' : "";
        
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML =
        "hover: &lt;" + tagName.toLowerCase() + id + "&gt;";
    }
}, 100);
```

```css
.listQue {
 list-style-type: none;
}
.listAns {
 list-style-type: none;
}
 li {
 display: inline;
}

.O1, .O2 {
 display: inline-block;
}

.A1, .A2, .A3, .A4, .A5 {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 3px solid black;
}

.B1, .B2, .B3, .B4, .B5 {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 3px solid black;
}


td {
border:3px solid black;
width : 200px;
background : green;
}

table  {
    border-color:black;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border-spacing: 0px;
 height : 200px;
}


#start {
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

body {
 background-color : #90C3D4
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="raspuns">
<ul class="listAns">
<li><div class="A1">1</div></li>
<li><div class="A2">2</div></li>
<li><div class="A3">3</div></li>
<li><div class="A4">4</div></li>
<li><div class="A5">5</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

using `setInterval(function(){

```
var element = $(':hover');
if(element.length)
{
    var domElement = element[element.length - 1];
    var tagName = domElement.tagName;
    var id = domElement.id ? ' id="' + domElement.id + '"' : "";

    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML =
    "hover: &lt;" + tagName.toLowerCase() + id + "&gt;";
}
```

}, 100);` using setInterval function its show just id , but i want to get class.

Comment: There is too much code, you should isolate that relative to the question, then what's the question?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/7pubnh1e/

Answer (score 0):

To get the class, just use "domElement.className". You might want to consider using an eventListener instead of the timer. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp